# Knockout: Load observable array with ajax on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am having issues with binding back selected options to a dropdown

Here is my code:

```
@Html.SelectListFor(m => m.State,
new { data_bind = "options: availableStates,  optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'Id', selectedOptions: selectedStates
    })
```

On my page load I want to set my options on this dropdown so I have the following knockout code:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: rootDir + "/Home/GetStates",
            type: "GET",                
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonResult1 = JSON.parse(data);                    
                data1 = jsonResult1;
                for (key in jsonResult1) {
                    var item = {
                        Id: jsonResult1[key].Id,
                        Name: jsonResult1[key].Name
                    };
                    self.availableStates.push(item);
                }
            }
       });

  self.selectedStates = ko.observableArray(vmData.State || "");
  //vmData.State has the previous selected values from the db
```

My issue is when I debug the code above, the above ajax call is executed at the last and the selectedStates statement is executed before. Since ajax call is executed afterwards the dropdown is empty and there is nothing to set in the dropdown.

Can I directly place my above ajax code in my knockout js file and it load the availablestates observable array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a public method in your viewmodel which handles the ajax-call and the pushing to availableStates observable. When you instantiate your VM you can call this method before applyBindings.

edit: probably typo but still:

```
@Html.SelectListFor(m => m.State,
new { data-bind = "options: availableStates,  optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'Id', selectedOptions: selectedStates
    })
```

data-bind not data_bind

Comment: I just tried that. Same thing happens my KO code for selected states is executed first and then at last my call to ajax happens where populates available states

Comment: self.selectedStates = ko.observableArray(vmData.State || ""); move this up above the ajax call

Comment: not sure but this does not work either. Now what I tried was, I have moved the ajax call to my html and then have assigned the value that I get from my ajax return to a hidden variable. I then use this value in my KO to populate my available states. The weird issue now is this only works when my chrome debug window is open. When I close the window and run my app as it is, this does not work. I have deleted my cache/cookies etc. Have even tried to debug by putting various alerts. One alert says my hidden variable is empty because of which states ddl is empty. Not sure whats going on here.

Comment: it sounds like a timing issue - opening the debug window and maybe hitting a breakpoint changes the order your script would get executed. I suggest you start looking in that direction to make it work.

Comment: Cant get through this, not sure whats going on here. If I create a hard code list of states, the entire thing works fine. As soon as I put an ajax call, it just doesnt works. Any other way to populate this arry.

Comment: Can you update your post with your entire vm and maybe view?

Comment: I got it working by populating the model itself. The code is spread out a lot and am sure there is something that not going right in that. Am good for now and look at it when I have more time.